# Simplify function Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

here is a function I have for creating a new Contact.

It works fine and as expected.

What I would like to know is if there is a better way or best practice to simplify and improve the code.

I am simply looking to improve my skills and build more efficient functions.

```
public function onSave()
    {

        $validator = Validator::make(
            [
                'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                'phone' => Input::get('phone'),
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'line_1' => Input::get('line_1'),
                'line_2' => Input::get('line_2'),
                'line_3' => Input::get('line_3'),
                'city' => Input::get('city'),
                'state' => Input::get('state'),
                'postcode' => Input::get('postcode'),
                'organisation_id' => Input::get('organisation_id'),
            ],
            [
                'firstname' => 'required',
                'lastname' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'line_1' => 'required',
                'line_2' => '',
                'line_3' => '',
                'city' => 'required',
                'state' => 'required',
                'postcode' => 'required',
                'organisation_id' => 'required',
            ]
        );

        if($validator->fails()){

            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);

        } else {

        $contact = new Contact();

        $contact->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
        $contact->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
        $contact->phone = Input::get('phone');
        $contact->email = Input::get('email');
        $contact->line_1 = Input::get('line_1');
        $contact->line_2 = Input::get('line_2');
        $contact->line_3 = Input::get('line_3');
        $contact->city = Input::get('city');
        $contact->state = Input::get('state');
        $contact->postcode = Input::get('postcode');
        $contact->organisation_id = Input::get('organisation_id');

        $contact->save();

        //Flash::success('Form Submitted');

        return Redirect::to('/contacts/'.$contact->id);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Look up form requests in the Laravel docs. That should be a good start. Then make the fields fillable on the Contact model and fill them using the $request->only() method

Comment: If your code works and you just want someone to review it, please post it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks man for your link.. honestly didn't knew about that before ))

Comment: No worries. It's not easy to keep track of all the different Stack Exchange sites :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have better code, definitely:

- Instead of using a `Validator` in your controller, refer to use [`Form Requests`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation).
- Try to use `$request` or `request()` facade instead of `Input` (just because this is the standard).
- When redirecting to a page different than the actual, try to use `route('route name')` so it is more readable for anyone and less prone to malforming URLs.

---

So, let me show you the final code (I will be using `Laravel 8` and `PHP 8`):

First create the `Form Request` (I will use a random name):

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreContact extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'line_1' => 'required',
            'line_2' => '',
            'line_3' => '',
            'city' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'postcode' => 'required',
            'organisation_id' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

So then, the controller should look like this:

```php
use App\Http\Requests\StoreContact;

public function onSave(StoreContact $request)
{
    $contact = new Contact();

    $contact->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
    $contact->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $contact->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $contact->email = $request->input('email');
    $contact->line_1 = $request->input('line_1');
    $contact->line_2 = $request->input('line_2');
    $contact->line_3 = $request->input('line_3');
    $contact->city = $request->input('city');
    $contact->state = $request->input('state');
    $contact->postcode = $request->input('postcode');
    $contact->organisation_id = $request->input('organisation_id');

    $contact->save();

    return redirect(route('contacts.show', ['contact' => $contact->id]);
}
```

And your route should be something like this:

```php
Route::get('/contacts/{contact}', [ContactController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('contact.show');
```

So, when you use a `Form Request`, it will automatically validate your input using the rules you supplied, and if any rule fails, it will return to the previous URL (`redirect()->back()`) with errors (`->withErrors()`) and with input (`->withInput()`).

This means that, if you are in the controller (from the first line of your method an on) everything is validated and authorized. You have green light.